# ExtJs Type Error

Tags: javascript, extjs

When I trying to add new row in the grid was the error `h is undefined`.I've tried understand why and I found that if scroller was in the down of scrollbar all was right,but if it was in other position was the error. I've tried to override `ensureVisible` because error was in that function but without any result and it's the library function I don't want to override that,error was in the row  `var cleft = parseInt(cellEl.offsetLeft, 10);` ,so how can I resolve this bug?

```
   Ext.override(Ext.grid.GridView, {
        ensureVisible : function(row, col, hscroll) {

            var resolved = this.resolveCell(row, col, hscroll);
            if(!resolved || !resolved.row){
                return;
            }

            var rowEl = resolved.row,
                cellEl = resolved.cell,
                c = this.scroller.dom,
                ctop = 0,
                p = rowEl,
                stop = this.el.dom;

            var p = rowEl, stop = this.el.dom;
            while(p && p != stop){
                ctop += p.offsetTop;
                p = p.offsetParent;
            }
            ctop -= this.mainHd.dom.offsetHeight;

            var cbot = ctop + rowEl.offsetHeight;

            var ch = c.clientHeight;
            var stop = parseInt(c.scrollTop, 10);
            var sbot = stop + ch;

            if(ctop < stop){
                c.scrollTop = ctop;
            }else if(cbot > sbot){
                c.scrollTop = cbot-ch;
            }

            if(hscroll !== false){
                var cleft = parseInt(cellEl.offsetLeft, 10);
                var cright = cleft + cellEl.offsetWidth;

                var sleft = parseInt(c.scrollLeft, 10);
                var sright = sleft + c.clientWidth;
                if(cleft < sleft){
                    c.scrollLeft = cleft;
                }else if(cright > sright){
                    c.scrollLeft = cright-c.clientWidth;
                }
            }
            return this.getResolvedXY(resolved);
        },

    });
    this.libraryListGrid = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
        clicksToEdit: 1,
        selModel: new helpsys.AddRowSelectionModel({
            singleSelect: true
        }),
        colModel: new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
            columns: [
                {
                    header: '',
                    menuDisabled: true,
                    width: 33,
                    dataIndex: '',
                    fixed: true,
                    renderer: this.renderOrder
                },
                {
                    menuDisabled: true,
                    dataIndex: 'name',
                    editable: !this.config.viewOnly,
                    editor: new Ext.form.TextField({
                        allowBlank: true,
                        controllerThis: this,
                        autoCreate: {tag: 'input', type: 'text', maxlength: '10'},
                        listeners: {
                            blur: function(item){
                                var record = item.getValue();
                                record = Ext.util.Format.htmlEncode(record);
                                record = this.controllerThis.replaceAll("&apos;","'",record);
                                item.setValue(record);
                            }
                        }
                    }),
                    header: 'Library',
                    id: 'name'
                },
                {
                    header: '',
                    menuDisabled: true,
                    width: 35,
                    dataIndex: '',
                    fixed: true,
                    renderer: this.renderActions
                }
            ]
        }),
        ds: this.libraryListDataStore,
        height: 200,
        width: 'auto',
        allowEdit: true,
        listeners: {
            rowclick: {
                fn: onRowClick,
                scope: this
            }
        },
        forceValidation: true,
        loadMask: true,
        renderTo: 'libraryListGrid',
        stripeRows: true,
        tbar: [{
            disabled: this.config.viewOnly,
            cls: "library-list-add-button",
            text: "<span>Add </span>",
            handler : function(){
                var Plant = this.libraryListGrid.getStore().recordType;
                var p = new Plant({
                });
                var insertIndex;
                var selectedRecord = this.libraryListGrid.getSelectionModel().getSelected();

                if (selectedRecord) {
                    insertIndex = this.libraryListGrid.getStore().indexOf(selectedRecord) + 1;
                }
                else {
                    insertIndex = this.libraryListGrid.getStore().getCount();
                }
                this.libraryListGrid.stopEditing();
                this.libraryListGrid.getStore().insert(insertIndex, p);
                this.libraryListGrid.selModel.selectRow(insertIndex);
                this.libraryListGrid.startEditing(insertIndex, 1);
            },
            scope: this
        }],
        view:this.view


    });
},
```

Comment: Never heard of such problem. How do you add the new row?

Comment: You can see it in `tbar`in  functionality of the add button.

Comment: Which version of Ext is that? Looks like 3 or older because coding style of 4+ is different.

Comment: I see. The first thing I'd try to sort out would be if the problem is in the ensureVisible override. Comment it out and re-run.

Comment: no,problem is'n in overridden `ensureVisible` ,it's in defaulte function in ExtJs library I just tried override that.But I don't know how I can do that right.When I'm trying add new row in the line `var cleft = parseInt(cellEl.offsetLeft, 10);` is appear error about null cleft.